# ylim constrains data but not axis in plot output (WindR)

Tags: r, plot

I'm going through a tutorial for WindR (https://www.r-bloggers.com/plotting-wind-highways-using-rwind/) and following the instructions, but when it comes to plotting the data on a map the latitude bounds are much larger than the data range. The data ranges from latitudes of 20 to 60 while the map is outputting a much larger range.

Adjusting the ylim parameters to plot() as such did not change the data display:

```
# Finally, we can transform this data into a raster layer  
rmax <- rasterFromXYZ(maxw)  
acol <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "blue", "darkblue"))  
plot(rmax, col=acol(1000), main= "Maximum wind speed reported",  
     xlab="Longitude", ylab="Lattitude", ylim=c(20,60))  
#add world map lines
lines(getMap(resolution = "high"), lwd=2)
```

The data is loaded using the following code

```
library(rWind)  
library(lubridate)  
library(dplyr)  
library(rworldmap)  

# Here, we use ymd_hms from lubridate package to create a sequence of dates  

dt <- seq(ymd_hms(paste(2018,6,1,12,00,00, sep="-")),  
          ymd_hms(paste(2018,6,30,12,00,00, sep="-")),by="1 days")  

# Now we can use wind.dl_2 with this sequence of dates. Have into account  
# that it could take a while, they are 30 datasets and it's a big area.   

ww <- wind.dl_2(dt,-85,5,20,60)  

# After tidy our wind data, we can use dplyr utilities to easily  
# obtain several metrics from our wind data. Notice that wind average  
# is a special case, and it will be discussed later  
t_ww <- tidy(ww)  


g_ww <- t_ww %>% group_by(lat, lon)  

# Now, we select only the maximum speed values for each coordinate  
max_ww <- g_ww %>% summarise(speed = max(speed))  
maxw <- cbind(max_ww$lon, max_ww$lat, max_ww$speed)  
head(maxw)

# Finally, we can transform this data into a raster layer  
rmax <- rasterFromXYZ(maxw)  
acol <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "blue", "darkblue"))  
plot(rmax, col=acol(1000), main= "Maximum wind speed reported",  
     xlab="Longitude", ylab="Lattitude", ylim=c(20,60))  
#add world map lines
lines(getMap(resolution = "high"), lwd=2)
```

I expect the map to look like the example plot (on the website linked above), but my map has a much larger yaxis range that is not altered by adjusting the ylim (ylim does affect the data display if I go above 20 or below 60, but the y axis does not change.